# Forum software written in Python

Tags: python, forum

I'm looking for a modern, feature rich forum software (like [discourse](https://www.discourse.org/)) but written in Python. (Reason: I know Python better than Ruby).

Comment: What features are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: Modern UI, actively maintained...